# How to Redirect 301 with .php in the link

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

i have following problem, i cant Redirect 301 via .htaccess example:

```
Redirect 301 /wellnesshotel.php/fotogalerie/ /wellnesshotel/bilder-und-videos/
```

the page where the redirection comes is `http://www.domain.de//fotogalerie/` but why?

Thanks a lot

Comment: use incognito mode or clear the browser cache

Comment: i have already tried this... :(

Comment: can you show the full `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

```
    `
# BEGIN HTTPS Redirection Plugin
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS Redirection Plugin

# BEGIN WpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-domain.de
# Start WPFC Exclude
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wellnessurlaub/wellness-angebote [NC]
# End WPFC Exclude
# Start_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=Anke|Buckermann|MarcelM|Mudrich|Steffen
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=Taptap|Tina|Tobias|Valentin|Walera
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=Xenia
# End_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-domain.de
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|WhatsApp|Mediatoolkitbot)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !comment_author_
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wp_woocommerce_session
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !safirmobilswitcher=mobil
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(\bCrMo\b|CriOS|Android.*Chrome\/[.0-9]*\s(Mobile)?|\bDolfin\b|Opera.*Mini|Opera.*Mobi|Android.*Opera|Mobile.*OPR\/[0-9.]+|Coast\/[0-9.]+|Skyfire|Mobile\sSafari\/[.0-9]*\sEdge|IEMobile|MSIEMobile|fennec|firefox.*maemo|(Mobile|Tablet).*Firefox|Firefox.*Mobile|FxiOS|bolt|teashark|Blazer|Version.*Mobile.*Safari|Safari.*Mobile|MobileSafari|Tizen|UC.*Browser|UCWEB|baiduboxapp|baidubrowser|DiigoBrowser|Puffin|\bMercury\b|Obigo|NF-Browser|NokiaBrowser|OviBrowser|OneBrowser|TwonkyBeamBrowser|SEMC.*Browser|FlyFlow|Minimo|NetFront|Novarra-Vision|MQQBrowser|MicroMessenger|Android.*PaleMoon|Mobile.*PaleMoon|Android|blackberry|\bBB10\b|rim\stablet\sos|PalmOS|avantgo|blazer|elaine|hiptop|palm|plucker|xiino|Symbian|SymbOS|Series60|Series40|SYB-[0-9]+|\bS60\b|Windows\sCE.*(PPC|Smartphone|Mobile|[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3})|Window\sMobile|Windows\sPhone\s[0-9.]+|WCE;|Windows\sPhone\s10.0|Windows\sPhone\s8.1|Windows\sPhone\s8.0|Windows\sPhone\sOS|XBLWP7|ZuneWP7|Windows\sNT\s6\.[23]\;\sARM\;|\biPhone.*Mobile|\biPod|\biPad|Apple-iPhone7C2|MeeGo|Maemo|J2ME\/|\bMIDP\b|\bCLDC\b|webOS|hpwOS|\bBada\b|BREW).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond /usr/www/users/zumckp/ice-media/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
##### mobile #####
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-domain.de
# Start WPFC Exclude
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wellnessurlaub/wellness-angebote [NC]
# End WPFC Exclude
# Start_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=Anke|Buckermann|MarcelM|Mudrich|Steffen
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=Taptap|Tina|Tobias|Valentin|Walera
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=Xenia
# End_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-domain.de
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|WhatsApp|Mediatoolkitbot)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !comment_author_
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wp_woocommerce_session
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !safirmobilswitcher=masaustu
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(\bCrMo\b|CriOS|Android.*Chrome\/[.0-9]*\s(Mobile)?|\bDolfin\b|Opera.*Mini|Opera.*Mobi|Android.*Opera|Mobile.*OPR\/[0-9.]+|Coast\/[0-9.]+|Skyfire|Mobile\sSafari\/[.0-9]*\sEdge|IEMobile|MSIEMobile|fennec|firefox.*maemo|(Mobile|Tablet).*Firefox|Firefox.*Mobile|FxiOS|bolt|teashark|Blazer|Version.*Mobile.*Safari|Safari.*Mobile|MobileSafari|Tizen|UC.*Browser|UCWEB|baiduboxapp|baidubrowser|DiigoBrowser|Puffin|\bMercury\b|Obigo|NF-Browser|NokiaBrowser|OviBrowser|OneBrowser|TwonkyBeamBrowser|SEMC.*Browser|FlyFlow|Minimo|NetFront|Novarra-Vision|MQQBrowser|MicroMessenger|Android.*PaleMoon|Mobile.*PaleMoon|Android|blackberry|\bBB10\b|rim\stablet\sos|PalmOS|avantgo|blazer|elaine|hiptop|palm|plucker|xiino|Symbian|SymbOS|Series60|Series40|SYB-[0-9]+|\bS60\b|Windows\sCE.*(PPC|Smartphone|Mobile|[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3})|Window\sMobile|Windows\sPhone\s[0-9.]+|WCE;|Windows\sPhone\s10.0|Windows\sPhone\s8.1|Windows\sPhone\s8.0|Windows\sPhone\sOS|XBLWP7|ZuneWP7|Windows\sNT\s6\.[23]\;\sARM\;|\biPhone.*Mobile|\biPod|\biPad|Apple-iPhone7C2|MeeGo|Maemo|J2ME\/|\bMIDP\b|\bCLDC\b|webOS|hpwOS|\bBada\b|BREW).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/wpfc-mobile-cache/$1/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond /usr/www/users/zumckp/ice-media/wp-content/cache/wpfc-mobile-cache/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/wpfc-mobile-cache/$1/index.html" [L]
##### mobile #####
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "index\.(html|htm)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END WpFastestCache
# BEGIN GzipWpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype font/ttf font/eot font/otf
</IfModule>
# END GzipWpFastestCache
# BEGIN LBCWpFastestCache
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/webp A2592000
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/ico A2592000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A2592000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Expires "max-age=2592000, public"
Header unset ETag
Header set Connection keep-alive
FileETag None
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END LBCWpFastestCache
# BEGIN WEBPWpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpe?g|png)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f [or]
RewriteCond /usr/www/users/zumckp/ice-media/$1.webp -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/$1.webp" [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
</IfModule>
AddType image/webp .webp
# END WEBPWpFastestCache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# WORKING REDIRECTS
RewriteEngine On

Redirect 301 /hotel/wellnessurlaub.php/bernkastel-kues /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z/
Redirect 301 /wellness/wellnessreisen.php/verwoehnhotel /wellnesshotel/bilder-und-videos/
Redirect 301 /hotel-buchen/wellnesshotel.php/hotel/angebote-pauschalen.html /wellnessurlaub/
Redirect 301 /hotel-buchen/wellnesshotel.php/hotel/zimmer /wellnessurlaub/zimmer/
Redirect 301 /hotel-buchen/wellnesshotel.php/hotel/anwendungen/ /wellnessurlaub/anwendungen/
Redirect 301 /dayspa/ /wellnessurlaub/day-spa/
Redirect 301 /bewei/ /wellness/bewei/
Redirect 301 /tcm/traditionelle-chinesische-medizin.php/alternative-medizin /tcm/
Redirect 301 /beauty/medical-beauty.php/schoenheitsfarm /wellness/spa/
Redirect 301 /restaurant/vitalhotel.php/fuenf-elemente-kueche /wellnesshotel/kulinarik/
Redirect 301 /freizeit/fitness-hotel.php/ferien/ /wellnesshotel/mosel-und-freizeit/wander-und-spazierwege-ab-hotel/
Redirect 301 /aktuelles/urlaub-deutschland.php/mosel/ /wellnesshotel/ueber-uns/news/
Redirect 301 /videos/ /wellnesshotel/bilder-und-videos/
Redirect 301 /wellness-abc/ https://www.my-domain.de/wellness/wellness-abc/
Redirect 301 /urlaub/rueckruf-service/ /kontakt-infomationen/kontakt/
Redirect 301 /wellnesshotel.php/urlaub/rueckruf-service/ /kontakt-infomationen/kontakt/
Redirect 301 /wellnesshotel.php/urlaub/anreise /wellnesshotel/anreise-und-entfernungen/
Redirect 301 /wellness-abc/ /wellness/wellness-abc/

Redirect 301 /angebote /wellnessurlaub/wellness-angebote/

Redirect 301 /wellnesshotel.php/urlaub/gaestebuch/gaestebuch /
Redirect 301 /wellnesshotel.php/angebote /wellnessurlaub/wellness-angebote/
Redirect 301 /wellnesshotel.php/urlaub/kontakt /kontakt-infomationen/kontakt/
Redirect 301 /wellnesshotel.php/urlaub/gutschein/ /wellnessurlaub/wellness-gutschein/
Redirect 301 /wellnesshotel.php/urlaub/wellnesshotel-prospekte/ /kontakt-infomationen/service/wellnesshotel-prospekte/
Redirect 301 /wellnesshotel.php/urlaub/uebersicht /sitemap/
Redirect 301 /wellnesshotel.php/urlaub/impressum /impressum/
Redirect 301 /wellnesshotel.php/urlaub/presse-center /kontakt-infomationen/kontakt/
Redirect 301 /wellnesshotel.php/urlaub/shops /tcm/shop/
Redirect 301 /wellnesshotel.php/urlaub/newsletter /kontakt-infomationen/service/newsletter/

Redirect 301 /angebote-und-preise/wellness.php/wellness-angebote/ /wellnessurlaub/wellness-angebote/
Redirect 301 /angebote-und-preise/wellness.php/wellness-angebote /wellnessurlaub/wellness-angebote/


# NOT WORKING REDIRECTS
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /hotel/wellnessurlaub.php/bernkastel-kues/blackvip-im-wellnesshotel-zum-kurfuersten /kontakt-infomationen/service/black-vip/
Redirect 301 /aktuelles/urlaub-deutschland.php/mosel/stellenangebote/ /wellnesshotel/ueber-uns/jobs/
Redirect 301 /hotel/wellnessurlaub.php/bernkastel-kues/nachhaltigkeit /wellnesshotel/ueber-uns/nachhaltigkeit
Redirect 301 /hotel/wellnessurlaub.php/bernkastel-kues/ausstattungsmerkmale /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z/
Redirect 301 /hotel/wellnessurlaub.php/bernkastel-kues/serviceleistungen /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z/
Redirect 301 /hotel/wellnessurlaub.php/bernkastel-kues/gesellschaftliches-und-soziales-engagement /wellnesshotel/ueber-uns/nachhaltigkeit/
Redirect 301 /hotel/wellnessurlaub.php/bernkastel-kues/entfernungen /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z/
Redirect 301 /angebote-und-preise/wellness.php/wellness-angebote/hotel/an-und-abreise /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z/
Redirect 301 /angebote-und-preise/wellness.php/wellness-angebote/hotel/bezahlung-storno /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z/
Redirect 301 /angebote-und-preise/wellness.php/wellness-angebote/hotel/saisonzeiten /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z/
Redirect 301 /angebote-und-preise/wellness.php/wellness-angebote/hotel/fruehstueckszeiten /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z/
Redirect 301 /angebote-und-preise/wellness.php/wellness-angebote/hotel/fuer-kinder /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z/
Redirect 301 /angebote-und-preise/wellness.php/wellness-angebote/hotel/hunde-mitbringen /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z/
Redirect 301 /angebote-und-preise/wellness.php/wellness-angebote/hotel/unsere-kueche /wellnesshotel/kulinarik/
Redirect 301 /angebote-und-preise/wellness.php/wellness-angebote/hotel/wissenswertes /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z/

Redirect 301 /restaurant/vitalhotel.php/fuenf-elemente-kueche/gutes-essen-haelt-leib-und-seele-zusammen /wellnesshotel/kulinarik
Redirect 301 /restaurant/vitalhotel.php/fuenf-elemente-kueche/waffelrezept-ein-bisschen-gesund /wellnesshotel/kulinarik/
Redirect 301 /restaurant/vitalhotel.php/fuenf-elemente-kueche/speisekarte-mittag /wellnesshotel/kulinarik/
Redirect 301 /restaurant/vitalhotel.php/fuenf-elemente-kueche/speisekarte-abend /wellnesshotel/kulinarik/
Redirect 301 /restaurant/vitalhotel.php/fuenf-elemente-kueche/vital-schlemmen /wellnesshotel/kulinarik/
Redirect 301 /restaurant/vitalhotel.php/fuenf-elemente-kueche/einzigartige-kueche /wellnesshotel/kulinarik/

Redirect 301 /wellness/wellnessreisen.php/verwoehnhotel/tcm-wellness-abc /tcm/alternative-medizin/tcm-glossar/
Redirect 301 /wellness/wellnessreisen.php/verwoehnhotel/praeventionsangebote /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z/
Redirect 301 /wellness/wellnessreisen.php/verwoehnhotel/wellnessurlaub-mosel /wellnesshotel/mosel-und-freizeit/
Redirect 301 /wellness/wellnessreisen.php/verwoehnhotel/fitness-cardio-fitness /wellness/kurse-aktivitaeten/fitness/
Redirect 301 /wellness/wellnessreisen.php/verwoehnhotel/praeventions-kurse /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z/
Redirect 301 /wellness/wellnessreisen.php/verwoehnhotel/panorama-schwimmbad /
Redirect 301 /wellness/wellnessreisen.php/verwoehnhotel/wellness-im-hotel-zum-kurfuersten /
Redirect 301 /wellness/wellnessreisen.php/verwoehnhotel/zuschuesse /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z/
Redirect 301 /wellness/wellnessreisen.php/verwoehnhotel/wellness-hotels-resorts /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z/


# enable php compression
php_value zlib.output_compression 1
php_value zlib.output_compression_level 6

# enable apache compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/* text/* font/* image/x-icon image/svg+xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>`
```